# ORA-00933 trigger exception - SQL command not properly ended

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I have the following code which compiles with an error- SQL command not properly ended
    create or replace trigger trg_bc
      after insert on Marks
      for each row
      declare
        sumMarks int;
        noCMarks int;

```
    begin
      select nbrMarks into noCMarks from Course where idC = :new.idC;

      select count(idC) from Marks where idStd = :new.idStd and idC = :new.idC;

      if (noCMarks = Marks) then
        select sum(Mark) into sumMarks from Marks where idC = :new.idC
        and idStd = :new.idStd;
        select nbrMarks into noCMarks from Course where idC = :new.idC;
      insert into meanbyCourse (idStd, IdC, Mean) values(:new.idStd, :new.idC, sumMarks/ noCMarks);
      end if;
  end;
/
show errors
```

I don't know what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This part has gone a bit wrong - line 26 as the error message pointed to:

```
select count (*) into rowcnt from Course where idc =    marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdC := :new.IdC and nbrMarks in
(select count(idC) from Marks where idStd = marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdStd and idC = marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdC := :new.IdC);
```

You've got an assignment, `:=`, in the middle of that, twice. I'm not sure quite what this is supposed to be doing:

```
where idc =    marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdC := :new.IdC
```

And the same thing is in the subquery. I guess you cut-and-paste that from a few lines above and got too much of it? If so:

```
select count (*) into rowcnt
from Course
where idc = marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdC 
and nbrMarks in (
  select count(idC)
  from Marks
  where idStd = marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdStd
  and idC = marks_change_tab(marks_change_tab.last).IdC
);
```

i.e. just remove `:= :new.IdC` from those lines. I'm not really following what you're doing here, but since it's in a loop, it looks like you mean to be referring to `marks_change_tab(i)` throughout that, not the `.last` value? Although unless I'm missing something it will only have one row anyway, making it a bit pointless. You can't refer to `.last` inside an SQL statement (you'll get a PLS-00425 error), so you need to use `i` there and in the other select statements in that loop.

```
select count (*) into rowcnt
from Course
where idc = marks_change_tab(i).IdC
and nbrMarks in (
  select count(idC)
  from Marks
  where idStd = marks_change_tab(i).IdStd
  and idC = marks_change_tab(i).IdC
);

if (rowcnt >0) then
  select sum(Mark) into sumOfStdMarks
  from Marks
  where idC =  marks_change_tab(i).idC
  and idStd = marks_change_tab(i).idStd;

  select nbrMarks into nbrOfCourseMarks
  from Marks
  where idC = marks_change_tab(i).idC;

  marks_change_tab(i).mean := sumOfStdMarks/ nbrOfCourseMarks;
else
  marks_change_tab.delete(i);
end if;
```

(Updated to include `delete`, from comments). But if there's only one row you might as well skip the loop and use the `:new` values directly. And there is no `marks.nbrMarks` column; not sure if you mean to get that from `course`?

The second error is as Rene already pointed out; you're trying to insert a single value (which is a record) into three columns. You need to specify each value from your record explicitly as Rene showed. It doesn't matter that the `insert` and the record type both have three columns, they are not directly compatible. You could instead declare the record type differently:

```
subtype mbcourse_rec is meanbycourse%rowtype;
type m_change_tab is table of mbcourse_rec;
```

... and then you can do:

```
insert into meanbyCourse values marks_change_tab(i);
```

[This compiles now, anyway](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/c7e836).

A trigger doesn't seem to be the way to go here though. It seems like it would be easier to make `meanByCourse` a view that calculates the values on the fly, or possibly a materialised view, or have a procedure that does the calculations and performs the insert into `marks` and `meanByCourse` at the same time, though that would have the same concurrency issues. Similarly it looks like you're probably calculating `course.nbrMarks` from a trigger or prior to the insert that this trigger fires against, which may also be prone to concurrency issues. Hard to tell really, but it all seems quite complicated and messy.

Comment: thanks a lot folx, it compiles without errors now but when i try to insert a single record it gives me the error saying i can't insert null values into meanbyCourse table. I tried to put in an else statement within the IF block -      Please advice 
if….
else
      insert into Marks values (:new.IdStd, :new.IdC, :new.Mark, :new.dateExam);
end if;
This should allow a new record be inserted if the condition isn't met but it doesn't work.

Comment: Your trigger is on `marks`, so you shouldn't be trying to insert another record into that table. If you aren't setting `marks_change_tab(i).mean` then there's maybe something off in your `nbrMarks` value or comparison - which I suggested might be a problem. You need to look at the logic of that calculation, figure out if you have the data, and if what you're doing with it is right. Can't tell what the problem is without the data, I can only speculate.

Comment: let's consider these insert values -
insert into Student (fName, lName) values ('Lue', 'Mitcham');

insert into Course (nameCourse, nbrMarks) values ('Java', 3);

insert into Marks (IdStd, IdC, Mark, dateExam) values (1, 1, 45, '21-Jan-13');
insert into Marks (IdStd, IdC, Mark, dateExam) values (1, 1, 64, '12-Dec-12');
the trigger is expected to calculate the mean after the third entry (Java, 3) because 3 marks complete the java entry so the previous records for marks should enter without a calculation

insert into Marks (IdStd, IdC, Mark, dateExam) values (1, 1, 24, '24-Jan-13');

Comment: You don't want to calculate the mean until after the third entry, or whatever the `nbrMarks` value is? One option is to delete the `marks_change_tab` row if you can't set the mean, I suppose, so it doesn't get inserted later? [Like this](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/cfe43/1).

Comment: Yes, the trigger checks how many marks completes a course and in this case (Java, 3) 3 is nbrMarks. So i want the the 3rd record entry to make the mean calculation. The nbrMarks values isn't the same for all courses so it checks for this value in all cases and should only calculate the mean when it's reached.

Answer (score 1):

"Not enough values" means you are trying to do an insert statement and the column list is longer than the values list. Check your insert statement. Probably need to change it to:

```
insert into meanbycourse
   (idstd
   ,idc
   ,mean)
values
   (marks_change_tab(i).idstd
   ,marks_change_tab(i).idc
   ,marks_change_tab(i).stdmean);
```

Comment: Actually, it isn't longer- these are the tables involved